# Performing an automatic segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm downloading remote JSON data and want my loading screen to stay up until the download is complete. Once my parse method finishes running, a segue should be called to move to the next view automatically.

I've verified that my data is properly downloading and parsing. My performSegue function is even being called when I throw up a breakpoint. But the application is still not moving to the next view.

Here's where I'm calling my parse method and then immediately calling the desired segue:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    downloadSources(atURL: "https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "loadingFinished", sender: self)
}
```

For reference, if you need it, here is my parse method in its entirety:

```
func downloadSources(atURL urlString: String) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    if let validURL = URL(string: urlString) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: validURL)
        request.setValue("49fcb8e0fa604e7aa461ee4f22124177", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Api-Key")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                assertionFailure()
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data

                else {
                    assertionFailure()
                    return
            }

            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                    guard let sources = json["sources"] as? [[String: Any]]

                        else {
                            assertionFailure()
                            return
                    }

                    for source in sources {
                        guard let id = source["id"] as? String,
                        let name = source["name"] as? String,
                        let description = source["description"] as? String

                            else {
                                assertionFailure()
                                return
                        }

                        self.sources.append(Source(id: id, name: name, description: description))
                    }
                }
            }

            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                assertionFailure()
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debug using overriding _prepareForSegue_ method. Check the destination controller and check your identifier.

Comment: Are you aware that `performSegue` is called immediately after `downloadSources` **without** waiting until the download is complete due to the asynchronous behavior of `dataTask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a closure callback is what you want.

```
typealias CompletionHandler = ((_ success:Bool) -> Void)?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadSources(atURL: "www.example.com", completion: {
            if success {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "loadingFinished", sender: self)
                return
            }
            // otherwise deal with failure
    })
}

func downloadSources(atURL urlString: String, completion: CompletionHandler) {
    if error != nil {
        completion?(false)
        return
    }
    // finish downlaod
    completion?(true)
}
```

Comment: `if completion !=  nil { completion!(true) }` is very *objective-c-ish*. In Swift there is Optional Chaining. Write simply `completion?(true)`. And the typealias is supposed to be `... = ((Bool) -> Void)?`. The parameter label is not used at all when the closure is called.

Comment: I'm sure I'm making silly mistakes. This solution does appear to partially work as I'm able to print to the console from the destination controller. However, the destination view itself is still now showing.

Comment: Nevermind! I was able to get it to work properly by calling super.viewDidLoad in the closure. Thank you!

Comment: @vadian is correct I updated the execution of the closure to utilize optional chaining.